DataCloud: How to ingest ExpenseReport object from Sales Cloud (since Cloud Integration User license doesn't allow Read on ExpenseReport)
We are trying to bring some Service objects from our Salesforce instance into Data Cloud.
The first step in doing so is to allow Read and View All permissions for desired objects in Data Cloud Salesforce Connector permission set that was automatically generated in the source SF org after we connected it to Data Cloud.
After permissions are granted in the source org, only then objects become available for selection when creating data stream in Data Cloud instance.
Everything works great with majority of objects (e.g. Case, WorkOrder, ServiceAppoitnment, ServiceResource, TimeSheet etc.), but when we try to grant Read and View All access for ExpenseReport object and save Data Cloud Salesforce Connector permission set, the system throws the following error:
Can't save permission set Data Cloud Salesforce Connector, 
which is assigned to a user with user license Cloud Integration User. 
The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read Expense Reports

It seems that Data Cloud CRM connector is leveraging Platform Integration User in source org by default (which has this autogenerated Data Cloud Salesforce Connector permission set assigned), and license of this user (named Cloud Integration User license) doesn't support working with some objects, like ExpenseReport in our case.
The question here is: how can we bring then objects like ExpenseReport into Data Cloud? Can we somehow bypass this user license restriction? Can we enforce CRM Connector to use another user/license/permset in source org? Or should we put aside CRM Connector and leverage alternative ways to bring such "non-supported" objects (e.g. via ingestion api)?
Any help/ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I would raise a case and see if there is a way to allow the permissions

@MohithShrivastava SF support aknowledged this as a product limitation, documented it here, right at the bottom of the page (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000397109&type=1) and suggested to create idea on IdeaExchange. Seems like there are no quick workarounds, except using something like Ingestion API, which involves some level of complexity for sure.

please add as an answer to help everyone

SF support aknowledged this as a product limitation, documented it here by appending ExpenseReport and ExpenseReportEntry objects to the list of not supported objects by CRM Connector right at the bottom of the page, and suggested to create idea on IdeaExchange.
In general, seems like there is no quick workaround as of now (May 1, 2024), except using something like Ingestion API, which involves high level of complexity for sure, or go with some ugly solution like duplicating standard objects into custom ones that can be migrated by CRM Connector.
